# Facebook PHP SDK + codeigniter + index.php removing = not working

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using facebook-php-sdk with my codeigniter application.
I have a problem with authentication when I'm trying to get rid off index.php from my URL.

My implementation of facebook connect is simple and works fine. (sdk core files are a library, and cofig file with app data) Authentication works great when I'm typing:

```
myapp.com/index.php/welcome
```

but when I'm trying:

```
myapp.com/welcome
```

I can click and click and click on login - and page just refreshes.

My Welcome controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // Your own constructor code
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $CI->config->load("facebook",TRUE);
    $config = $CI->config->item('facebook');
    $this->load->library('facebook', $config);
}

public function index()
{
    echo CI_VERSION;
    $user = $this->facebook->getUser();
    if($user) {
            $user_info = $this->facebook->api('/me');
            echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($user_info, true)).'</pre>';
    } else {
        echo "<a href=\"{$this->facebook->getLoginUrl()}\">Login using Facebook</a>";
    }
}
```

Simple as that: when authenticated it just prints my fb account data.

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /index\.php/?([^ ]*)
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?(.*) /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond $0 !^index\.php($|/)
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L]
```

**UPDATE**

My login url from mysite.com/welcome **NOT WORKING**

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=487********73&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fwelcome&state=ae51191b8eabf884ead0c116e7e28b4d
```

and from mysite.com/index.php/welcome **WORKING FINE**

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=487********73&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Findex.php%2Fwelcome&state=ae51191b8eabf884ead0c116e7e28b4d
```

Comment: have you set `$config['index_page'] = '';` in `application/config/config.php`?

Comment: @goldenparrot - yes I have : )

Comment: Can you show us what is the login url?

Comment: Ok, check update in my post : )

Comment: Your `.htaccess` code seems to produce an error on my local server. Have you tried the cleaner htaccess code described in the CI docs: [Codeigniter URLs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html). Also: is welcome your default controller? In this case you don't need to call `/welcome`; you should be able to redirect to your site root.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try using a different .htaccess? I've used this one on some CI projects with FB with no trouble:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    ### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

    # If your default controller is something other than
    # "welcome" you should probably change this
    RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes access to the system folder by users.
    # Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    # previously this would not have been possible.
    # 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

And consider what froddd says, ig your default controller is welcome, then you can use just www.yoursite.com instead or www.yoursite.com/welcome